# Naming of files using actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, filenames, flex4.5

i create an application using Adobe flex 4.5 for recording videos and i was wondering how to give appropriate names to my files produced. What i was thinking is to give the current timestamp which is unique what's your opinion, is there a better solution and how can it be implemented using actionscript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't going to be a correct answer for "appropriate". Timestamp is a reasonable idea; if the creation of videos is user-driven you could always prompt them (but default to the current time) for a name. You can generate the date strings with `new Date().toString()`. If the default format isn't what you want a `DateFormatter` class can be used to generate your own.